# How to general new text boxes upon clicking a button?

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

I have around 600 Records in a table. These are the names of **Items** as displayed in the image. To issue **Items** to users, we at the Stationery first enter the **Quantity** of each **Item** to be issued and then submit the form.

What I want to do is this:

I want this form to be dynamic. We should enter the name of the **Item** (This I will do using Autocomplete). Then We want to enter the **Quantity**, and then **Remarks**. After finishing one such Record, I want to display a button **Make another entry**. And this button should generate three text boxes: **Item**, **Quantity**, and **Remarks** ... and again upon clicking the same button, one more such row should be generated...

Just like in Android mobile phone, a single contact can have many phone numbers. And upon entering one phone number, there comes a button which says **Add another phone number**. I want to do something like this.

Please help.

As of now, I am displaying all the records in the table in an HTML form using PHP loops, which is a tedious task and a bad design.

Can you please tell me if there is any way out.

Thanks in advance.

[image: HTML Form that is currently in use]

Comment: And this particular problem has nothing to do with MySQL, right? Ajax might be a better tag

Comment: Alright. Edited the tags!

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery to add the elements on click of a certain button.

As example:

#### html:

```
<html>
    <head>
    ...
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="items">
            <div class="item1">
                <input type="text" name="...">
                ....  
            </div>
        </div>
        <button class="addElements">Add Item</button>
    </body>
</html>
```

#### javascript/jquery:

```
$('button.addElements').on('click', function() {
    $('<div class="item2>....</div>').appendTo('.items');
});
```

In each itemX div you will put your input's and everything you need for one item.